# In a canvas, is there a way to tell when an img.src is done loading?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to convert the canvas to dataURL after adding an image to the canvas. The issue I am having is having the dataURL created before the image is done being loaded onto the canvas. Is there a way to tell when the image is done loading?

```
        var myCanvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        var ctx = myCanvas.getContext('2d');
        var img = new Image;
        img.onload = function(){
          ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
        };
        img.src = URL;
```

```
document.getElementById("imgURL").value = myCanvas.toDataURL();
```

Comment: Yes, and you are already using it: `img.onload`. So just do your work from that callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're already using the `img.onload` handler which is run after the image is done loading. Since `ctx.drawImage` is *synchronous*, the image is guaranteed to be rendered on the canvas *before* the next line code is executed.

So what you should do is simply run `myCanvas.toDataURL()` in the `onload` callback and after you `drawImage` and you'll get a Base64 of the canvas that includes the image, like so:

```
img.onload = function(){
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
  document.getElementById("imgURL").value = myCanvas.toDataURL();
}
```